# Не скрывать элемент если нажат второй блок.

Tags: javascript, ajax

Вот пример работы на http://jsfiddle.net/ghkEY/98/

```js
$('.nav__top-level li').click(function(){
var links =  $('.sub-menu li').children();
var arrLinks = [];
links.each(function(index,element)
{
if(index >= 1)
arrLinks.push($(element).attr('href'));''
});
$('#sub-menu a').each(function(index,element){
$(element).attr('href',arrLinks[index]);
console.log(arrLinks);
});
});
```

```html
<nav class="nav nav__top-level"><ul id="menu-top-menu" class="">
<li id="menu-item-134" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Сервис</a>
<nav id="sub-menu" class="nav nav__second-level" style="display:none;"> <ul>
 <li id="menu-item-131"  ><a href="http://excellence-new.ru/category/bez-rubriki/">Без рубрики</a></li>
</ul></nav>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-15"  class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">instagram</a>
<nav id="sub-menu" class="nav nav__second-level" style="display:none;">
<ul>
 <li id="menu-item-132" ><a href="http://excellence-new.ru/category/obuv-i-aksesuari/">Обувь и Аксессуары</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-133" ><a href="http://excellence-new.ru/category/odejda/">Одежда</a></li>
</ul></nav>
</li>
</ul></nav>

 


      <nav class="nav nav__second-level" >
         <ul id="sub" style="display:none;">
             
             </ul>
       </nav>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при раскрытом меню, нажав на другой главный пункт меню, текущие элементы заменились бы, но при этом анимация или не сработала бы или раскрылась по новой.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#sub').html(newLinks);
  if ($(this).hasClass('activeMenu')){
   $('.nav__second-level').children('#sub').slideUp('slow');
   $(this).removeClass('activeMenu');
  } else{
      $('.nav__second-level').children('#sub').hide().slideDown('slow');
      $('.menu-item-has-children').removeClass('activeMenu');
      $(this).addClass('activeMenu');
  }
```

Обновил фидл. 
http://jsfiddle.net/moonvvell/ghkEY/101/

Comment: Но тогда при повторном клике на тот же самый пункт меню - выпадающий пункт не будет скрываться. =)

Comment: вы попробовали? http://jsfiddle.net/moonvvell/ghkEY/99/

Comment: Конечно. Вы скинули пример там так как я говорю .

Comment: Магия :) потому как у меня все работает прекрасно. клик на "Сервис" или "instagram" открывает меню. сколько раз кликаем столько раз и открывает.

Comment: Ну так а закрывает при повторном клике?

Comment: обновил фидл - http://jsfiddle.net/moonvvell/ghkEY/101/